# Expression not working on Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, mustache, ractivejs

Expressions are not working for me on my Ractive.js proyect. I am just trying to run a stupid expression like:

```
{{ 5 * 3 }}
```

But I am getting on the console a error for each expression that I try that it says something like this:

```
Failed to compute @5*3: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Same with each new expression that I tried on my templates. I have tried a few possibilities (custom functions, computed functions, etc), even I did the HTML empty and I wrote just a expression but I always get the same error. It works when I bind a variable, but again it does not work anymore if I try to use an operator like +, /, * or calling a custom function.

Any idea? It is quite strange. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the relevent code? HTML that is throwing this error?

Comment: This is the relevant the code. Javascript console is throwing this error.

Comment: This basic code works perfectly fine in examples on the site. So there is something different in the  way you are using it.So please add the basic code that you used(the HTML template) which threw this error.

Comment: [Expressions work](https://ractive.js.org/playground/#N4IgFiBcoE5SAbAhgFwKYGcUgL4BoQN4AlJAYxQEsA3NACmAB0A7RlFJGAczRUgAIA5ACMA9gBMAnoLws26ALYAHZOgGDgwfgFZ+AKn4BmfjhyCWOAJS4gA). Not exactly sure how you're using it, which may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Ractive -->
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ractive'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target" class="container"></div>

    <script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
        {{ 5*3 }}
    </script>

    <script>
        var page = 0; // an evil global variable ;)
        var ractive = new Ractive({
            el: '#target',
            template: '#template'
     });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you see in this basic example it works, you might have some syntax error and the problem is elsewhere